# Draw line chart dynamically using database values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, charts

i am trying to draw line chart , but don't know how to pass dynamic database values in LineChart using jquery ?

i have already searched , but could not find answer in stack.

i am passing two fields : 
1) date-time  (Y axis)
2) no of downloads on that date (X axis)

Does any body used this kind facility in their website? which plugin should i use?

this is html

```
<section class="panel corner-flip">
<header class="panel-heading no-borders">
  <h2><strong>LINE</strong> Chart </h2>
  <label class="color">Plugin <strong> Flot chart in table</strong></label>
</header>
<div class="widget-chart chart-dark">
  <table class="flot-chart" data-type="lines" data-tool-tip="show" data-width="100%" data-height="220px">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th style="color : #3db9af;">Page View</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <th>JAN</th>
           <td>295</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>FEB</th>
           <td>3145</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>MAR</th>
           <td>1515</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>APR</th>
           <td>4578</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>MAY</th>
           <td>4041</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>JUN</th>
           <td>12090</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>JUL</th>
           <td>4235</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>AUG</th>
           <td>1215</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>SEP</th>
           <td>2315</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>OCT</th>
           <td>5315</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>NOV</th>
           <td>2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>DEC</th>
           <td>315</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this is js file...

```
var     bars = false,
lines = true,
pie=false;
var     createFlot=function($chageType , $change){ 
var el=$("table"+($change ? $change:".flot-chart"));
el.each(function() {      
    var colors = [], data = $(this).data(),
    gridColor=data.tickColor || "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
    $(this).find("thead th:not(:first)").each(function() {
             colors.push($(this).css("color"));
    });
    if($chageType){
        bars = $chageType.indexOf("bars") != -1;
        lines = $chageType.indexOf("lines") != -1;
        pie = $chageType.indexOf("pie") != -1;
        $(this).next(".chart_flot").hide();
    }else{
        if(data.type){
            bars = data.type.indexOf("bars") != -1;
            lines = data.type.indexOf("lines") != -1;
            pie = data.type.indexOf("pie") != -1;
        }
    }
$(this).graphTable({ series: 'columns', position: data.position || 'after',  width: data.width, height: data.height, colors: colors },
 {
    series: { stack: data.stack ,    pie: { show: pie , innerRadius: data.innerRadius || 0,  stroke: {  shadow: data.pieStyle=="shadow" ? true:false } , label:{ show:data.pieLabel } }, bars: { show: bars , barWidth: data.barWidth || 0.5, fill: data.fill || 1, align: "center"  } ,lines: { show: lines  , fill:0.1 , steps: data.steps } },
    xaxis: { mode:  data.mode || "categories", tickLength: 0 },
    yaxis: { tickColor: gridColor ,max:data.yaxisMax,
    tickFormatter: function number(x) {  var num; if (x >= 1000) { num=(x/1000)+"k"; }else{ num=x; } return num; }
                                    },  
    grid: { borderWidth: {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 1, left: 1},color : gridColor },
    tooltip: data.toolTip=="show" ? true:false  ,
    tooltipOpts: { content: (pie ? "%p.0%, %s":"<b>%s</b> :  %y")  }
                            });
                    });
        }
        // Create Flot Chart
        createFlot();

        $(".chart-change a").click(function (e) {
                var el=$(this),data=el.data();
                el.closest(".chart-change").find("a").toggleClass("active");
                el.closest(".chart-change").find("li").toggleClass("active");
                createFlot(data.changeType,data.forId);
        });

        $(".label-flot-custom").each(function () {
            var el=$(this), data=el.data() ,colors = [] ,lable=[] , li="";
                $(data.flotId).find("thead th:not(:first)").each(function() {
                              colors.push($(this).css("color"));
                              lable.push($(this).text());
                });         
                for(var i=0;i<lable.length;i++){
                    li += '<li><span style="background-color:'+ colors[i] +'"></span>'+ lable[i] +" ( "+$(data.flotId).find("tbody td").eq(i).text()+' ) </li> ';
                }
                el.append("<ul>"+li+"</ul>");
                if($(data.flotId).prev(".label-flot-custom-title")){
                    var height=$(data.flotId).next(".chart_flot").css("height");
                    $(data.flotId).prev(".label-flot-custom-title").css({"height":height, "line-height":height });
                }
        });
```

Comment: show us your code where LineChart initializes and the array you are passing from php

Comment: minus vote for what??

Comment: @Viral.. now suggest me answer please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example this will help you to solve your question.

here is link to this example: [line charts example](http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Simple-Canvas-Based-Line-Chart-Plugin-For-jQuery-Topup.html)

and you can change labels on x- axis using this syntax:

```
labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

just try to change like this in php

```
    labels: [
     <?php foreach($month as $value){
       echo '"'.$value.'"'; 
      }
     ?>]
```

Comment: This library is the most simple you could ask for. Its perfect for me, thanks for the heads up, there is too many pricing model library that do the same thing, and this is just 1 file.